# execute shell script from desktop in xfce

Tags: scripts, xfce, .desktop

At first I just made a link to the .sh file on my desktop which failed to execute by double click. Then I've read about .desktop files and made one still to no avail. The program I want to run is a shell script with various parameters for executing jar file.
My ./desktop file looks as follows:

```
[Deskto Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=jessator
Comment=starts the jess UI
Exec=/home/alf/Software/Jessator/runJessator.sh
Icon=/home/alf/Software/Jessator/jess-32x32.gif
Type=Application
Terminal=false
```

Since the script launches from the terminal, it is correct, however since it does not really used the terminal, I don't want to open terminal window to run it.
Setting Terminal=true did not help either.

EDIT:
The script I am launching:

```
java -cp $JESSATOR/Jessator.jar:/home/alf/JESS/Jess71p2/lib/*:$JESSATOR/TimerBean.jar Jessator
```

Comment: It is executable, if I open terminal and call the script from there it executes. I thought about just running it that way with & at the end, but even if  do that, the program is closed when I close the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

You have misspelling in the first line of your .desktop file

```
[Deskto Entry]
```

should be

```
[Desktop Entry]
```

Answer (score 0):

The general thing that comes to mind first is, **Is your script executable?** 
You can set this in the terminal by typing

`chmod +x yourfile.sh`

Or in a graphical way -

> Right click file -> Properties -> "Permissions" Tab -> Check box
>   "Allow this file to run as a program"

Answer (score 0):

There must be permissions issues because this works just fine for me:

```
mbiber@linux-pc ~/Desktop $ cat T2M.desktop 
[Desktop Entry]
Comment=Toggle second monitor display
Terminal=false
Name=2ndMonitorToggle
Exec=/usr/local/bin/toggle-screen.sh > /dev/null 2>&1
Type=Application
Icon=/usr/share/icons/screen_icon_white.png
Name[en_US]=T2M
```

Comment: Can it have something to do with the script calling a java jar with classpath given as one of the parameters?

Comment: We cant know since you haven't pasted the script.

Comment: edited the original post, now it holds the exact script